# Free embedded SQL for .NET with Latin2

Tags: .net, sql

Seeking a **embedded** database that meets the following conditions:

- free
- support VB.NET
- supports accented characters (e.g. Latin2, unicode) without external extension (SQLite and ICU)
- support UPPER, LOWER, SORTING with accented characters
- support the GROUP_CONCAT function or other function which allows the group commas separate
- support autoincrement integer without writing scripts and Others (e.g Firebird)
- Is not needed to install. There is enough to copy some dll files for the program.

Sorry my bad english!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). It small, self-contained and has bindings for a lot of languages, including C#. It's free and supports unicode, so handling latin2 characters shouldn't be any problem (I haven't tried this though).

EDIT: seems SQLite [won't sort accented characters](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18) by default:

> The default configuration of SQLite only supports case-insensitive
>   comparisons of ASCII characters.

It should be possible to write your own Unicode handling, but I guess that would require some C programming.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQLite does not handle accented characters!

E.g: Szállítóé (in VB.NET app) --> SzĂˇllĂ­tĂłĂ© (in SQLite)

And sort by Name accentuated when the text is placed in the bottom of the list.

Comment: @Zserigta Last time I checked, it supported UTF8 which would support most characters. As far as sorting these characters go, the FAQ has something to say about it: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't handle accented characters? Note that if you use the SQLite command line tool to output from the database, it is limited by the abilities by the command prompt. However, what happens when you read strings back into VB.NET?

Comment: When i read string back into VB.NET then the correct accents.
AND the Accent does not work with the LOWER and UPPER functions.
AND the sort by name is not good!

Comment: @Zserigta The FAQ entry I linked to explicitly mentions `LOWER` and `UPPER` and non-ASCII characters...